# How can I check selected radiobuttons when the radiobuttons have been added dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I've added my radio buttons like this dynamically:

```
foreach(DataRow row in results.Rows) {
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
    radioButton.ID = "reason_" + row["reasonName"].ToString();
    radioButton.GroupName = "reason";
    radioButton.Text = row["reasonName"].ToString();
    div.Controls.Add(radioButton);
    myValueDiv.Controls.Add(div);
}
```

I have a button on my page. How to know which radio button is selected (checked) when the user clicks it?

Comment: what about iterating through all the Radio Controls of myValueDiv and simply checking which one are selected. Can be done in one line using Linq Query.

Answer (score 0):

This should help, as I mentioned in my comment

```
var checkedRadioButtons = myValueDiv.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(radButton => radButton.Checked);
```